# Two Or more HTTP calls based on some conditions using zip operator of Rx Java

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to fire 3 HTTP Api calls using Android `RxJava` through zip operator.

My problem is, while triggering 3 API's, for one API,I need to check whether the user is logged in or not. If user is not logged in I should not trigger three API calls(I should have to trigger only two API calls). If User is logged in then I have to trigger 3 API calls. Any built in methods to trigger two or three API calls based on conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that should work pretty well.  Let me know if your method to check if a user is logged in is asynchronous and I will post a followup answer:

```
public Observable<Type> getUserData(){
    if(getCurrentUser() != null){
        return Observable.zip(api1(), api2(), api3(), (1, 2, 3) -> {
            *Combining Function*
        });
    }else{
        return Observable.zip(api1(), api2(), (1, 2) -> {
            *Combining Function*
        });
    }
}
```